# How to avoid move of possibly-uninitialized variable for MutexGuard interface?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

for following code:

```
  let conversation_model =
    if lsm { CONVMODEL.lock().await } else {
      conv_model_loader()
    };
```

`CONVMODEL.lock().await` is `MutexGuard<T>` and `conv_model_loader()` is just `T`

I need common interface for those two so I can not copy-paste my code for two situations because it will only differ with this type, anything else is the same.

Edit:

there is code ... (at least what I was trying to do)

```
  let (locked, loaded);  // pun not intended
  if lsm {
    locked = CONVMODEL.lock().await;
  } else {
    loaded = conv_model_loader();
  };
  let mut chat_context = CHAT_CONTEXT.lock().await;
  task::spawn_blocking(move || {
    let conversation_model = if lsm { &*locked } else { &loaded };
```

but I've fialed becuse of

```
use of possibly-uninitialized variable: `locked`\nuse of possibly-uninitialized `locked`
```

So question is really how to have `MutexGuard` with interface `&T` but use it inside `spawn_blocking` and also with `#[async_recursion]`

Edit:

```
  let (mut locked, mut loaded) = (None, None);
  if lsm {
    locked = Some( CONVMODEL.lock().await );
  } else {
    loaded = Some( conv_model_loader() );
  };
  let mut chat_context = CHAT_CONTEXT.lock().await;
  task::spawn_blocking(move || {
    let (lock, load);
    let conversation_model =
      if lsm {
        lock = locked.unwrap();
        &*lock
      } else {
        load = loaded.unwrap();
        &load
      };
```

following code is working but actually very ugly XD
(I wonder if it is possible to simplify this code)

Comment: You should simply use the code from the accepted answer, i.e. move the definition to `conversation_model` out of your closure, and only check `lsm` once.

Comment: (The accepted answer at the time I wrote the comment was user4815162342's.)

Comment: can't lock await inside spawn_blocking

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I suggested moving the assignment to `conversation_model` _out of_ the closure, using exactly the code in user4815162342's answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I agree user4815162342's approach is correct in general, but it was answering an incomplete question since OP did not include full context. That approach will not work with `spawn_blocking` since it needs to move `conversation_model` into the closure with `'static` lifetime, and that is not the case for the temporaries being stored in `locked` and `loaded`. You have to actually move the source of the references into the closure to achieve that and make your reference post-move. I'll edit my answer to explain this difference.

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks! The point I was missing is that the closure passed to `spawn_blocking()` needs to be `'static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have some set of choices for a value, you want to reach for `enum`. For example, in Rust we don't do things like `let value: T; let is_initialized: bool;`, we do `Option<T>`.

You have a choice of two values, either an acquired mutex or a direct value. This is typically called "either", and there is a popular Rust crate containing this type: [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/). For you it might look like:

```rust
    use either::Either;

    let conv_model = if lsm {
        Either::Left(CONVMODEL.lock().await)
    } else {
        Either::Right(conv_model_loader())
    };

    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        let conversation_model = match &conv_model {
            Either::Left(locked) => locked.deref(),
            Either::Right(loaded) => loaded,
        };

        conversation_model.infer();
    });
```

[*(Full example.)*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b026cf9742cbd3e676c8d678024cdca8)

This type used to live in the standard library, but was removed because it wasn't often used as it's fairly trivial to make a more descriptive domain-specific type. I agree with that, and you might do:

```rust
pub enum ConvModelSource {
    Locked(MutexGuard<'static, ConvModel>),
    Loaded(ConvModel),
}

impl Deref for ConvModelSource {
    type Target = ConvModel;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            Self::Locked(guard) => guard.deref(),
            Self::Loaded(model) => model,
        }
    }
}

// ...

let conv_model = if lsm {
    ConvModelSource::Locked(CONVMODEL.lock().await)
} else {
    ConvModelSource::Loaded(conv_model_loader())
};

tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
    conv_model.infer();
});
```

[*(Full example.)*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f07a454b09c92ca161f89d6331ece89)

This is much more expressive, and moves the "how to populate this" away from where it's used.

---

In the common case you do want to use the simpler approach user4815162342 showed. You will store one of the temporaries, form a reference to it (knowing you just initialized it), and hand that back.

This doesn't work with `spawn_blocking`, however. The lifetime of the reference is that of the temporaries - handing such a reference off to a spawned task is a dangling reference.

This is why the error messages (of the form "borrowed value does not live long enough" and "argument requires that `locked` is borrowed for `'static`") guided you to go down the path of trying to move `locked` and `loaded` into the closure to be in their final resting place, *then* form a reference. Then the reference wouldn't be dangling.

But then this implies you move a possibly-uninitialized value into the closure. Rust does not understand you are using an identical check to see which temporary value is populated. (You could imagine a typo on the second check doing `!lsm` and now you're switched up.)

Ultimately, you have to move the source of the value into the spawned task (closure) so that you form references with usable lifetimes. The use of enum is basically codifying your boolean case check into something Rust understands and will unpack naturally.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract `&mut T` from both and use that. Something like the following should work:

```
let (locked, loaded);  // pun not intended
let conversation_model = if lsm {
    locked = CONVMODEL.lock().await;
    &mut *locked
} else {
    loaded = conv_model_loader();
    &mut loaded
};
```

Comment: can't ask question in 90 minutes LOL (I hate stackoverflow), but my idea isn't working and I still need help, so I will edit this question (I guess)